# Find $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. the second derivative ($x=0$) of a function exists.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Find $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. the second derivative ($x=0$) of the following function exists.

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-\frac{1}{x}},  & \text{if $x$}\gt 0 \\[2ex]
\sin(x)+\alpha x^2-\log(1+x), & \text{if $x$ } \leq0
\end{cases}$

How to deal with this kind of exercise? Is it enough to use Taylor at second order and then looking for the differentiability of the function?

Comment: $e^{-1/x} $ doesn't have a Taylor series centered at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Taylor at second order means that you have already calculated the second derivative. Just calculate the second derivative on the left and on the right, and make them equal. $$\left(e^{-\frac 1x}\right)''=-\frac{2x-1}{x^4}e^{-\frac 1x}$$
This term goes to $0$ as $x\to 0$.
For the other side the second derivative is $$-\sin x+2\alpha+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$$
The limit at $0$ is $2\alpha+1$. So $2\alpha+1=0$ should give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The function is continuous at $0$, by checking the limits.

The derivative is
$$
f'(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{e^{-1/x}}{x^2} & x>0 \\[4px]
\cos x+2\alpha x-\dfrac{1}{1+x} & x<0
\end{cases}
$$
Since the limits of $f'$ for $x\to0$ from the left and from the right are both equal to $0$, we can say that the function is differentiable at $0$ and that the derivative is continuous. It follows from l'Hôpital's theorem.

Now apply the same technique, with the difference that
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x)=0
$$
(check it) and
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}\left(-\sin x+2\alpha+\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\right)=2\alpha+1
$$

A *sufficient* condition for differentiability of $f'$ at $0$ is $\alpha=-1/2$. Is it also necessary? Note that l'Hôpital can be used only one way.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

> A function whose right and left derivatives are given in a point, is
>   differentiable at that point if those right and left derivatives are
>   equal.

Based on this, try to differentiate the function twice, each time checking for which values of $a$ are the right and left derivatives in $x=0$ equal.